How can I add a visualized queue of items when the capacity in a storage unit is full using Salabim or Python in general?
I'm using the Python module Salabim and need help managing a store called "Yellow." This store has a capacity limit of 5 (set to infinity for demonstration purposes). Items are continuously added to the Yellow store via a route-based system. Once an item enters the Yellow section, it should be removed from the system after five seconds. If the store reaches its capacity, incoming items should queue outside until space becomes available. Then, the next item in the queue should move into the Yellow section. This process should continue until all items are processed.
Here is a basic code example of how items move on a route to yellow, while being stored there:
import salabim as sim

class Route(sim.Component):
    def setup(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2
        self.line = sim.AnimateLine(
            spec=(x1, y1, x2, y2),
            linewidth=30,
            linecolor='white'
        )

class ConnectionPoint(sim.Component):
    def setup(self, x, y, color, layer):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        sim.AnimateRectangle(
            spec=(-15, -15, 15, 15),
            x=x,
            y=y,
            fillcolor=color,
            layer=layer
        )

class Item(sim.Component):
    nr = 0
    def setup(self, routes):
        self.routes = routes
        self.current_route_index = 0
        self.has_been_stored = False
        self.x, self.y = routes[0].x1, routes[0].y1
        sim.AnimateRectangle(
            spec=lambda: (self.x - 12, self.y - 12, self.x + 12, self.y + 12),
            fillcolor="green"
        )
        Item.nr += 1
        self.id = Item.nr

    def process(self):

        # route 0
        if self.current_route_index == 0:
            while self.x != routes[0].x2:
                self.hold(0.1)
                self.x += (routes[0].x2 - routes[0].x1) / abs(routes[0].x2 - routes[0].x1) * 2
                self.current_route_index += 1
        if self not in yellow:
            self.enter(yellow)

env = sim.Environment()
env.background_color('20%gray')

yellow = sim.Store("yellow", capacity=float('inf'))

# Define list of routes
routes = [
    Route(x1=0, y1=700, x2=800, y2=700),     #
]

connection_points = [
    ConnectionPoint(x=800, y=700, color='yellow', layer=0),
]

# generates the item output
items = sim.ComponentGenerator(Item, routes=routes, iat=2, number=20)

env.animate(True)
env.run(till=200)

yellow.print_info()

Here's what I'm aiming for:

Visual Queue Representation:
Items should be displayed in a line, clearly showing the order of the queue.

Movement:
When an item is in yellow, after e.g. five seconds the item should dissapear and then a spot in yellow becomes available. The next item in line should move to yellow on the route.

Seamless Adaptation:
As items move from the queue to the yellow state, the queue should dynamically adjust.


However, I am struggling with the coding aspects required to configure these queue properties and behaviors. Could someone guide me on how to implement this in Salabim or in general for Pyhton? Any examples or snippets demonstrating this functionality would be greatly appreciated.
